# Screen Orientation Change

Tags: android, screen-orientation

How to properly handle screen orientation change in android? Whenever i change the orientation of my phone or whenever I rotate my phone, my activity crashes and will force close.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Post your errors and source code here.

Answer (score 0):

Activity restarts when the orientation changes.

If you want to avoid orientation changes , then disable it using
android:screenOrientation="portrait" (or landscape) in the manifest.
check here,
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Handling configuration changes yourself.